# Backup Evolution Mail

Tags: backup, evolution

I would like to backup my email that I have already downloaded and stored in Evolution.  I know there is an option in Evolution to backup your Evolution settings but how can you backup your mail accounts and mail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a backup by clicking File->Backup settings... in Evolution this will save you data and configuration.

Manually you should run `evolution –force-shutdown` first to make sure evolution is not using the files.

Then you can Backup:

- ~/.evolution (this saves your data)
- ~/.gconf/apps/evolution (and this your configuration)

Comment: I see the option File > Backup Settings. But does this not just backup the application preferences etc. or will it backup my mail as well?

Comment: The backup function in Evolution will backup everything: mail, calendar, notes. If you have multiple e-mail accounts as well. How mention c001os (except passwords).

Comment: Cool I'm happy with that :-)

Comment: Just be warned, by everything it means everything.  So if you have a large mail history such as on Gmail it will backup all of that too.  Even with Compression my backup is about 2GB.  It's a shame that there isn't a configuration only option.

Comment: i cant find `~/.evolution`  anymore. `File->Backup settings.` approach is creating only 15kb file. I am expecting my email backup to be in gb

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to backup all of your Evolution is to backup the (hidden) evolution folder in your home directory:

```
~/.evolution
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that archiving ~/.evolution does not produce the same result as 
File>Backup

So, the two methods mentioned by in answers are not equivalent.

Comment: How are they different?

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is go to File>Backup data (or something else). That will create an /home/yout_username/evolution-backup.tar.gz. This is the backup file with everything (except passwords).